# Why is my Jenkins TFS polling time in the future?

Tags: jenkins, tfs, jenkins-plugins

I have a jenkins job that is polling my TFS server. My TFS Server lives on AWS. It is finding changes that are happening in the future and starting my job. Here is what is displayed in the TFS Polling log.

```
Started on Sep 8, 2016 10:46:09 AM
Done. Took 0 ms
Changes found
```

Inside of my build console for this job shows this which makes me believe something is running on GMT time as it is exactly 6 hours ahead of my current timezone (MDT).

```
Querying for remote changeset at '$/XXXXXXXXX/Three/Dev' as of 'D2016-09-08T16:46:15Z'...
Query result is: Changeset #98532 by 'XXXXXXX' on '2016-09-08T13:58:27Z'.
```

It's stuck in an endless loop because that value is always in the future. I have checked everything to make sure it is on the correct timezone (Jenkins Master, Jenkins Node(slave), the Linux box Jenkins Master is installed on, the TFS server (front and backend))  I thought about setting the timezone for jeknins to GMT but that would mean all the jobs we have that run at certain times of the day would start to fail.

Answer (score 0):

From my test, the date and time in Console Output of Jenkins build is GMT time by default. There is nowhere to change this. If you check TFS log, you'll find it also use GMT time in log file and no where to change this.

[image]

[image]